# apache poi get default column type

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm using POI to create a new row of cells in an existing spreadsheet. POI allows you to get the column default style, but there's no equivalent (as near as I can tell) to getting a default type. I'm getting a String from my user interface and I don't know how to set the cell type. If the string is a double, then fine, it's NUMERIC. But if the String specifies a date, how would I best detect it so that it is also set to NUMERIC? There are some many formatting types for a date that it is impractical to detect the type from the cell style format. Does POI support a way to parse based on a format?

Comment: [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) will take a cell's contents + format rules, and output the string the represents it. Is that what you need? Or are you trying to go the other way?

Comment: Sadly, I'm trying to go the other way. I already have the formatted data going to the user interface. Now I'm trying to take a string from the interface and install it as a brand new cell, i.e. a cell with no known type.

Comment: Are you allowing your users to ender any old random text, or are there a handful of known formats you're expecting?

Comment: Input is from a JTextField which may be associated with any cell, so I need the cell to determine if the input is valid and of what type. For new cells I only have the default column styles to work with but they can only format and not parse.

Answer (score 0):

To set the cell type you use:

```
setCellType()
```

as outlined in the docs:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/

> > setCellType void setCellType(int cellType) Set the cells type (numeric, formula or string). If the cell currently contains a value,
> >     the value will be converted to match the new type, if possible.
> >     Formatting is generally lost in the process however.
>
> If what you want to do is get a String value for your numeric cell,
>   stop!. This is not the way to do it. Instead, for fetching the string
>   value of a numeric or boolean or date cell, use DataFormatter instead.
>
> Throws: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if the specified cell
>   type is invalid java.lang.IllegalStateException - if the current value
>   cannot be converted to the new type See Also: CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC,
>   CELL_TYPE_STRING, CELL_TYPE_FORMULA, CELL_TYPE_BLANK,
>   CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN, CELL_TYPE_ERROR

Comment: I'm creating a brand new cell - no type available and only column default styles available. How to determine if it is a 'date' cell?

Comment: Example: User inputs "4/30", is this a fraction (numeric), a date (numeric), or a string? Excel manages to handle this by knowing the styles for a column but I don't see how I can tell given only the column's default style.

Comment: Not sure excel does know the style for a column, it seems to just randomly guess, not always correctly, unless you've explicitly applied formatting to the cell